# Why won't MKMapView stop showing user location?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

This is kinda the opposite of most questions on the topic.  My issue isn't getting the user's location to show; it's getting it to STOP showing.

I have a view with an MKMapView.  I set it's region equal to the user's current location, then I set it to not show the user location:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate=(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([appDelegate.locationManager location].coordinate, 1000, 1000)];
    [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];
    /*Unrelated code*/
}
```

Even if I move this code to ViewWill/DidAppear, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?  I've tested that self.mapView exists and is not null -- I even ran a debugger command 'po [self.mapView removeFromSuperview]' to confirm I had the RIGHT MKMapView (it vanished, as expected).

Comment: Have you checked the output of [self.map showsUserLocation]? If it is returning NO then your assignment there has worked and something else is showing your location. Maybe you've set the tracking mode and need to unset that with `setUserTrackingMode:animated`

Comment: It's returning 0, so I don't know what's going on.  This view is created fresh every time, and I don't use tracking modes...  and even adding setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone isn't helping.

Comment: As added info, the location that it's displaying does NOT update over time.  (I have another map view that does just that, so I can see that the location it's using is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a simulator bug.

Turns out the iOS 5 simulators put the location pin in, even when they're not supposed to.  Doesn't happen on device.